# Не могу проверить чекбокс

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Хочу проверить чекбокс, выбран ли он.

Делаю так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#forma_1").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/search.php',
      data: {
        var checkTr = $('#ID_368963829').is(':checked');
      }
    }).then(function(res_pole) {
      $("#summa_itogo").html(res_pole);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="forma_1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ID_368963829" name="n_368963829">
</form>
```

выдает ошибку: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

А если сделать так: - все работает.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#forma_1").change(function() {
    var checkTr = $('#ID_368963829').is(':checked');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/search.php',
      data: {
      }
    }).then(function(res_pole) {
      $("#summa_itogo").html(res_pole);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="forma_1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ID_368963829" name="n_368963829">
</form>
```

почему не работает первый вариант? и как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-determine-if-a-checkbox-is-checked

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так, наверное:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#forma_1").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/search.php',
      data: {
        ID_368963829: $('#ID_368963829').is(':checked')
      }
    }).then(function(res_pole) {
      $("#summa_itogo").html(res_pole);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="forma_1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ID_368963829" name="n_368963829">
</form>
```

Comment: нет нет. там мне нужна именно переменная

Comment: Но там синтаксически не может быть переменной. Это литерал объекта

Comment: @vp_arth понял. спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Этот метод будет более современен

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'
  $("#click-btn-result").bind("click", function() {
    var arrApp = [];
    $("#selectAppartaments input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
      arrApp.push($(this).val());
    });

    alert(arrApp);

  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="selectAppartaments">
    <label class="w-100 text-white text-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"  value="Студии" class="option-input checkbox" />
<span class="s-t-b">Студии</span>
</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="fancy-button pop-onhover bg-gradient3" id="click-btn-result" value="1"><span>нажми</span></button>
</form>
```